# Microsoft Windows 7 UI

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

Can any one tell me what Microsoft UI technology was used to create the UI of Windows 7. And what are they using now for Windows 8?

Answer (score 2):

The UI framework for Windows 7 was written with GDI/User and some Direct2D and GDI+.  The common controls play into the UI (most of the explorer UI is available as a common control for example).

Comment: thanks for the answer. Do you know what was used to write the Windows 8 UI and the Metro launcher?

Comment: As far as I know, the same - but with a lot more D2D and GDI+ and far less less GDI/User.